# how to translate sqlalchemy query correctly

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

all hi!

have a query

```
query = insert(balance)
query = query.on_conflict_do_nothing(
    index_elements=["query_id", "warehouse", "product"]
)
```

I use sqlalchemy compile for translation in raw sql

```
sql_str = (
        query.compile(
            dialect=postgresql.dialect(),
        )
    )
```

I get output

```
INSERT INTO balance (id, query_id, warehouse, product) VALUES (%(id)s, %(query_id)s, %(warehouse)s, %(product)s) ON CONFLICT (query_id, warehouse, product) DO NOTHING
```

how to get the?

```
INSERT INTO balance (id, query_id, warehouse, product) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (query_id, warehouse, product) DO NOTHING
```

full code:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import sys
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from typing import AsyncGenerator

import async_timeout
import asyncpgsa
import stackprinter
from faker import Faker
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, Table, MetaData, NUMERIC, func
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID, TIMESTAMP, insert
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer

metadata = MetaData()

stock_balance: sqlalchemy.table = Table(
    "stock_balance",
    metadata,
    Column("warehouse", UUID, primary_key=True),
    Column("product", UUID, primary_key=True),
    Column("balance", NUMERIC(15, 3), index=True),
    Column("reserve", NUMERIC(15, 3), index=True),
)

balance: sqlalchemy.table = Table(
    "balance",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("query_id", UUID(as_uuid=True), nullable=False, index=True),
    Column("warehouse", UUID, index=True, nullable=False),
    Column("product", UUID, index=True, nullable=False),
    Column("balance", Boolean, index=True, server_default="f"),
    Column("reserve", Boolean, index=True, server_default="f"),
    Column("count", NUMERIC(15, 3), nullable=False),
    Column("date_time", TIMESTAMP, server_default=func.now(tz="UTC"), index=True),
    Column("updated", Boolean, server_default="f", index=True),
)


def data_traffic():
    fake = Faker("ru_RU")
    balance = fake.boolean()
    return {
        "id": fake.uuid4(),
        "warehouse": fake.uuid4(),
        "product": fake.uuid4(),
        "balance": balance,
        "count": fake.pyfloat(left_digits=15, right_digits=3, min_value=0),
        "reserve": not balance,
    }


@asynccontextmanager
async def connect_db() -> AsyncGenerator:
    try:
        with async_timeout.timeout(5):
            conn = await asyncpgsa.create_pool(
                f"postgresql://postgres:some_secret@"
                f"localhost:10001/stockbalance_test",
                # echo=True,
                min_size=1,
                max_size=1,
                dialect=postgresql.dialect()
            )
            async with conn.acquire() as c:
                yield c
        await conn.close()
    except Exception as exc:
        logging.error(
            "Server Errors: {}\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(
                exc, sys.exc_info()[0], sys.exc_info()[1], stackprinter.format()
            )
        )
        yield None
    finally:
        await conn.close()


async def update_balance(conn, data: list):
    query = insert(balance)
    query = query.on_conflict_do_nothing(
        index_elements=["query_id", "warehouse", "product"]
    )
    sql_str = (
        query.compile(
            dialect=postgresql.dialect(),
        )
    )
    await conn.executemany(
        str(sql_str),
        [
            (
                item["id"],
                item["warehouse"],
                item["product"],
                item["balance"],
                item["reserve"],
                item["count"],
            )
            for item in data
        ],
    )


async def main():
    async with connect_db() as conn:
        try:
            await update_balance(conn, [data_traffic()])
        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

`syntax error at or near "%"`

Comment: Hello and welcome. Sorry but I don't get the question. Is it, that you want to use sqlalchemy as SQL generator, to copy the output and use it manually elsewhere?

Comment: yes I need to generate a request but in the form in which postgresql will understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution. Maybe someone will help. it looks like this

```
    query = insert(balance).values(
        [
            {
                "query_id": item["id"],
                "warehouse": item["warehouse"],
                "product": item["product"],
            }
            for item in data
        ]
    )
    query = query.on_conflict_do_nothing(
        index_elements=["query_id", "warehouse", "product"]
    )
    sql_str, args = compile_query(query)
    print("sql_str: ", sql_str)
    print("args: ", args)
    await conn.executemany(sql_str, [tuple(args)])
```

```
sql_str:  INSERT INTO balance (query_id, warehouse, product) VALUES ($2, $1, $3) ON CONFLICT (query_id, warehouse, product) DO NOTHING
```

```
args:  ['d982e84e-0f09-43dd-a296-aaf51dd6c36d', '4373a8df-0fd8-4f2f-855c-4a7b36a7ad9e', '831ce109-ff0f-4d0b-8c53-d148bb699bdf']
```